# Swift: AutoLayout constraints not behaving correctly when device rotates?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I am trying to make constraints for a "chat bubble-esque" view.

My problem is the view doesn't expand to 70% of the device's width, when the device is rotated.

Here is a picture to demonstrate what's going on.

When I rotate the device horizontally, notice on the blue bubble on the right-side device could expand to take up 70% of the space, instead, it keeps its current narrow-width:

[image]

Now, here is a picture of what I want to happen. When I rotate the device, can you see that the device on the right actually expands my custom view to 70% of the screen?

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the behaviour in the second image?

Here is my code for laying out my custom view using the SnapKit DSL:

```swift
bubble.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7).priority(.required)
    make.top.right.equalToSuperview().inset(20)            
}
```

[In case you are curious, here is a link to a GitHub Gist of my custom `bubble` view.](https://gist.github.com/josharnoldjosh/2a26a534eb6189f684595ca237e99455)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: My Updated Code:

```swift
bubble.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    
make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7).priority(.required)
    make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7).priority(.low)
    make.top.right.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
}
```

Comment: You are saying lessThanOrEqual and you are getting less than. You can’t complain! Less than is indeed less than or equal. If you mean equal why don’t you say equal? Is there some other reason why you don’t say that?

Comment: My bad, should have clarified! If the text is very small, such as "Hello", I do not want it to be equal, but instead `0.7 * lessThanOrEqualToSuperview`. But if the total text can exceed `0.7 * lessThanOrEqualToSuperview`, I would like to cap it at `0.7 * lessThanOrEqualToSuperview`. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another constraint that sets the width *equal* to 0.7 times the width of the superview, but at a lower priority (such as 100). This gives the layout engine something more to aim at when there is ambiguity — and an inequality is always ambiguous.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just realized, is your solution working when the text has very few characters, such as "hello"? For mine, there seems to be extra space on the right when the text has few characters (for example, looks like this: https://ibb.co/zZkMtXY), but when there are a decent amount of characters, it works perfectly (like in your example above!)? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong. I'll add screen shots showing my solution working for both long and short values.

Comment: Ah, maybe it is because I have my `UILabel` inside of a `UIView` and perhaps this messes up the intrinsic content size..? Would you know if this above method can still be applied to a `UIView` that contains a `UILabel`? From my tests, it works perfectly with just the `UILabel` but with a `UILabel` in a `UIView` it runs into some issues. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, there's no info about any of that in the question that was asked. The label should be able to size an immediate superview "from the inside out", but I know nothing of how you've set that up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this @matt, if you have any other spare time I would incredibly appreciate it if you might be able to take a quick look at my new stack overflow post building upon this solution (that has all the details), thank you again for your help! I feel I am very close to achieving my desired behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498793/swift-autolayout-acting-weird