# Swift: AutoLayout acting weird

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

Below is my dilemma and the steps I took to arrive at my situation.

**My First Step**

I create a class called `BubbleView`:

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit


class BubbleView : UIView {
    
    var label:UILabel!
    
    var text:String = "" {
        didSet {
            guard label != nil else {return}
            label.text = text
        }
    }
            
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        addSubview(label)
        
        label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

I create a view controller and add my `BubbleView`:

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var bubble: BubbleView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.bubble.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
    }
                        
    func setupUI() {
        bubble = BubbleView()
        bubble.text = "Hello"
        view.addSubview(bubble)
        
        bubble.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7).priority(.low)
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7)
            make.top.right.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).inset(20)
        }
    }
}
```

**My Problem**

My problem is, when I do `bubble.text = "Hello"`, there is a large amount of trailing space to the right as shown below:

[image]

I am trying to get rid of this trailing space so the image looks more like:

[image]

**What I need**

When the device is rotated into landscape mode, I need the `BubbleView` to resize to take up 70% of the screen, so it looks something like so:

[image]

So far, the bubble view does do this, but it always has the annoying trailing space as shown in the first image. By removing the following constraint on the `BubbleView`:

```swift
make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7).priority(.low)
```

It fixes the trailing space issue, however, when I rotate the device, the width doesn't update to 0.7 * the width of the device, as shown below:

[image]

**Help**

So, I am wondering if anyone knows how to remove the trailing space on the `BubbleView` when there is only a small amount of text, but still keep the behaviour when the device is rotated that it fills up `0.7 * screen width` if necessary, instead of keeping the same width.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I notice you didn’t do what I said in our earlier discussion. You are using `priority(.low)` for your equality constraint. That’s not what I said. I said 100. Did you try that? There is a reason I picked that number. Of course I could be wrong and I mean no offense, but you could at least try it before claiming my suggestion doesn’t work, since what you are doing is _not_ what I suggested. Thanks. (Sorry, can’t test for myself just now.)

Comment: My bad! Thank you very much for commenting. I have tried the 100 priority, and it fixes the problem with the extra trailing space, but when I rotate the device into landscape mode, the width of the view does not expand, it remains the same width that it was in portrait mode (i.e, the vertical orientation), when I was hoping for it to adjust to take up more of the available space. At this point, I am thinking there may be a bug with the `SnapKit` DSL..? Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: No idea, sorry, can’t test.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by eventually implementing my `UICollectionViewCell` class like this:

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit


class BubbleCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var label:UILabel!
    var background:UIView!
    
    var text:String = "" {
        didSet {
            guard label != nil else {return}
            label.text = text
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupUI(spacing:CGFloat=2) {
                    
        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        background = UIView()
        background.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        background.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        background.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(background)
        contentView.sendSubviewToBack(background)
                
        label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10 + spacing)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7)
        }
        
        background.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.label).inset(-10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.label).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(self.label).inset(-15)
            make.right.equalTo(self.label).offset(15)
        }
    }
}
```